# Code Analyze and Optimization tools for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I need to know tools available for performance analysis and optimization for Ruby on Rails like SonarQube in java.

Note : I am not looking for Gems.

Comment: What are you looking for if not a gem?

Comment: “I need to know...”—this is not an acceptable way of asking questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
https://github.com/railsbp/rails_best_practices

```
$ gem install rails_best_practices

$ cd <your_rails_app_folder>

$ rails_best_practices .
```

I think this helps you with terrible code.

Me personally, I would never use such a analysis tool, if you really want to write good code you should follow the rails guides, it helps a lot coding right.

Here's another attempt:
https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide

You should read this and get familiar with all the style guides of writing ruby code.

Answer (score 0):

Code climate is a tool for checking your rails application code and performance.
https://codeclimate.com

Comment: Its a paid tool . I am looking for free tool.